# Is it possible to create unpredictable random number with Solidity?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I have been researching this topic lately and most of the resources are saying that it's impossible to generate a random number on-chain. However, I have come across a post saying that this function can generate a unpredictable number. Is there any way to predict this function?

```
function rand() public view returns(uint256) {
    uint256 seed = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
        block.timestamp + block.difficulty +
        ((uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.coinbase)))) / (now)) +
        block.gaslimit + 
        ((uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender)))) / (now)) +
        block.number
    )));

    return (seed - ((seed / 1000) * 1000));
}
```

Comment: Creating unpredictable number is impossible by it self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there any way to predict this function?*

A miner can publish their block `number` with a `timestamp` that fits together with other criteria:

- `difficulty` is given for some time
- `coinbase` is given for even longer period of time
- `msg.sender` (the real transaction sender and signer) can be one of the miner's addresses

There's no way how to generate truly indeterminable random number on-chain. But you can use an oracle that returns an off-chain generated "random" number.

Comment: In terms of creating a dice game, what if we use future block to determine the winning number. Player will place the bet in current block and lock and with a second contract we are going to determine the winner. Would it be possible in this way?

Comment: If the possible winnings are big enough, the player can keep betting with the parameters of the possible next block that they are going to mine (until they in fact mine it with the expected parameters). The need for guessing correct `block.timestamp` that they are going to mine with a 1 second accuracy lowers the odds significantly, and it's plausible for most real-life use cases. But to answer the original question - it's still determinable (and not truly random)... Edit: The dishonest miner could also place multiple bets from multiple addresses in one block to higher their chances.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I really appreciate it.